# iOS 8 Beta 6 - Handling a UILocalNotification when the app is in Background

Tags: ios, notifications, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm creating an app for creating alarms. If the app isn't in background or inactive everything work fine. But if the app is inactive (because i've pressed home button or i've pressed the lock button) when the notification occurs, after sliding or touching the banner, the code isn't executed and the app doesn't complete its actions.

I've read a lot of topics here and on the web but nothing can help me. Documentation says:

> In iOS, you can determine whether an application is launched as a result of the user tapping the action button or whether the notification was delivered to the already-running application by examining the application state. In the delegate’s implementation of the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: or application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method, get the value of the applicationState property and evaluate it. If the value is UIApplicationStateInactive, the user tapped the action button; if the value is UIApplicationStateActive, the application was frontmost when it received the notification.

But application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method seems not to be called after sliding or tapping the notification. This method isn't called when a notification occurs and the app is inactive. How can execute the code for notification handling if app is inactive?

this is my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification!)
{

    if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active)
    {
        .

        println("Notification recieved and handled when inactive")

        .

    }

   .
   .
   .

}
```

All this code isn't executed when my application is in background or inactive or in lockscreen with my app still "alive" (when i push lock-screen button when my app is in foreground ). How can i handle Local Notification in these conditions? How can i recognize if the app is becoming active because of local notification occurs? I've found no solution to this problem.

Comment: ios8 is under NDA. You could ask it in the Apple DevForums

Comment: Further, Apple agrees that You will not be bound by the foregoing confidentiality terms with regard to technical information about pre-release Apple Software and services disclosed by Apple at WWDC (Apple's Worldwide Developers Conference), except that You may not post screen shots, write public reviews, or redistribute any pre-release Apple Software or services.

Comment: iOS 8 in not under NDA anymore. I ran into the same issue. Have you solved it?

Comment: Yes the right answer is below as @Daij-Djan said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### two cases:

1 . when your app is not running, only `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is called.
(either never was or was killed)

In that case, the launchOptions `NSDictionary` contain the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey` key

---

2 . if it is running -regardless of the state- `didReceiveLocalNotification` is called

In that case, use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState` to see where your app is

#### note: with ios8 there is more to do for this to work

Comment: Maybe you don't understand my question and is my fault because of my bad english. I'll try to explain better: My problem is how handle a local notification while the state of the app is "suspended". applicationDidFinishLaunching method is called at the first launch of the app, when it's not running (as you said). But my case concerns when the app is running but i click the home button or the lock-screen button. I hope this is more clear.

Comment: when the home button is pressed IOS can suspend the app OR close it

Comment: Ok. My problem is that none of this method is called. I've tryed to check the app state with NSLog(...) inside didReceiveLocalNotification, but when it is called nothing happen. If i have understood well if my app is in background when i tap on the notification banner the didReceiveLocalNotification method should be called, but nothing to do. I'm very frustrated!

Comment: iOS 8 Beta 6. Sorry i should put this on the question.

Comment: then did you do all the ios8 specific stuff? oh and it under NDA

Comment: What do you mean for "specific stuff"?

Comment: The problem is (at least for me) that if I build and run the code in the question using Xcode 5.1.1 (and iOS 7.1 SDK) on a device running iOS 8 beta 6 - it doesn't work. This is a bug in iOS 8, because the UILocalNotification behavior doesn't seem to be backwards compatible anymore.

Comment: there is no bug there AFAIK -- for me it works fine all the time ;)

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement with your use cases, wake up your notifications here 
. It will notify your app when it is in background and there is scheduled local notification time to get up..

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Answer (score -1):

On iOS, when the app is suspended because, for example, you pressed the lock button, you need to **change the notification priority to "high"**.
Here is a test code snippet that I've used before:

```
from gcm import GCM
import time
gcm = GCM('iOS Application ID issued by Google')
notification_topic = 'topic_name'
notification_text = '{"ticker": "XD", "company_name": "Vulchiany Technologies", "buy_target": "89.55", "profit_sell": "89.99", "loss_sell": "89.11", "alert_time": "' + time.strftime("%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p")+'"}'

for j in range(1,8):
    for i in range(1, 11):
        gcm.send_topic_message(topic=notification_topic, priority="high", notification={"body": "XD: Buy Target: $89.55", "title" : "Alert"}, data={'message': notification_text})
        time.sleep(3)
        print(notification_text)
        print('Notification sent on ', time.strftime("%b %d %Y %I:%M %p"))
    time.sleep(3600)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Please clarify why my response does not answer OP's question.  In his own words: "But my case concerns when the app is running but i click the home button or the lock-screen button. I hope this is more clear".  I've addressed exactly that point, and provided an example that is in actual use.  Thank you.

Comment: Most importantly, the question isn't about Google Cloud Messaging, it's referring to the iOS 8 SDK.